# Ctypes: WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000400 when calling C++ function

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

In my cpp file

```
extern "C" {
    Password obj;
    _declspec(dllexport) BOOL decrypt(const char *encryptedPassword, char *password, size_t *sizeOfThePasswordPtr)
    {
        return obj.decrypt(encryptedPassword, password, sizeOfThePasswordPtr);
    }
}
```

In my python file:

```
    lib = ctypes.WinDLL(os.path.join(baseDir, "basicLib.dll"))
    encryptedValue = ctypes.c_char_p('absfdxfd')
    decryptedValue = ctypes.c_char_p()
    size = ctypes.c_size_t(1024)
    lib.decrypt.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_size_t]
    lib.decrypt(encryptedValue, decryptedValue, size)
```

I got this error `WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000400` when calling the function. The problem is because `encryptedValue` argument.

It only work if I set `encryptedValue = ctypes.c_char_p()`, but I will get exception if I pass in some value. Please let me know why.

Comment: You don't seem to have allocated any memory to hold the decrypted value.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

```
# WinDLL is for __stdcall functions.  Use CDLL.
# This is most likely the cause of your exception because the parameters
# are marshalled on the stack incorrectly.
lib = ctypes.CDLL(os.path.join(baseDir, "basicLib.dll"))

# No need to explicitly create c_char_p objects if you declare argtypes,
# but make sure it is a byte string if using Python 3
encryptedValue = b'absfdxfd'

# Create a writable buffer for the output.
decryptedValue = ctypes.create_string_buffer(1024)

# Good
lib.decrypt.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_size_t]

# No need to declare explicit c_size_t() object either.
lib.decrypt(encryptedValue, decryptedValue, len(decryptedValue))
```